# My While loop isnt running properly in my python code for pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a function for smooth dodge movment in my game. I have a function that works in another file, but in my main game file the while loop doesnt work. I have added a print function before and after the loop and both are printed, but the one in the loop doesnt loop. It prints once and then it is done and done. The function is supposed to move the player by the amount of increment. How can I make my loop actually run as expected?

Here is my function

```
def dodge_multiple_dir(self, x_increment, y_increment, clock):        
    print("Hello World")
    while True:
        clock += speed_of_game_movement
        new_clock = round(clock / increment_for_every)
        if clock <= max_time:
            if new_clock * increment_for_every == clock:
                print("Debug")
                self.movement["left"] = False
                self.movement["right"] = False
                self.movement["up"] = False
                self.movement["down"] = False
                self.vel_x += x_increment
                self.vel_y += y_increment

        else:
            break
            
    print("Loop")
    return self.movement["left"], self.movement["right"], self.movement["up"], self.movement["down"]
    return self.movement["left"], self.movement["right"], self.movement["up"], self.movement["down"]
```

Here is the main code, just an fyi there are images but I have a github repo you can get the code from. https://github.com/DarthMooMancer/StackOverflow.

```
import pygame
from pygame import mixer
import math
from os import path
from settings import *
import sys

def init():
    pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 512)
    mixer.init()
    pygame.init()
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight), vsync=1)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Gloombound")
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', font_size[0])
    pixel_font = pygame.font.Font('Minecraft.ttf', font_size[1])
    
    return win, clock, font, pixel_font

def load_data(map_file):
    global map_data
    map_data = []
    game_folder = path.dirname(__file__)
    img_folder = path.join(game_folder, 'img')
    map_folder = path.join(game_folder, "maps")
    sound_folder = path.join(game_folder, "sounds")
    with open(path.join(map_folder, map_file), 'rt') as f:
        for line in f:
            map_data.append(line.strip())     
            
    return img_folder, sound_folder

def draw_text(text, font, color, surface, pos):
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, color)
    surface.blit(textobj, pos)

win, clock, font, pixel_font = init()
            
current_map = 'map.txt'
previous_map = ""
default_slider_pos = 500
img_folder, sound_folder = load_data(current_map)

# Load Images
play_img = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(path.join(img_folder,'play_button.png')), button_size).convert_alpha()
play_img_alt = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(path.join(img_folder,'play_button_alt.png')), button_size).convert_alpha()
quit_img = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(path.join(img_folder,'quit_button.png')), button_size).convert_alpha()
quit_img_alt = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(path.join(img_folder,'quit_button_alt.png')), button_size).convert_alpha()
continue_img = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(path.join(img_folder, 'continue_button.png')), pause_button_size).convert_alpha()
continue_img_alt = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(path.join(img_folder, 'continue_button_alt.png')), pause_button_size).convert_alpha()
main_menu = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(path.join(img_folder, 'main_menu_button.png')), pause_button_size).convert_alpha()
main_menu_alt = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(path.join(img_folder, 'main_menu_button_alt.png')), pause_button_size).convert_alpha()
settings_img = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(path.join(img_folder, 'settings_button.png')), pause_button_size).convert_alpha()
settings_img_alt = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(path.join(img_folder, 'settings_button_alt.png')), pause_button_size).convert_alpha()

# Load Sounds
player_hit = pygame.mixer.Sound(path.join(sound_folder, "player_hit.wav"))
player_mainclock = 0
global_volume = 99
new_volume = 10
mainclock = 0
max_time = 80
distance = 0
increment = 13
speed_of_game_movement = 3
increment_for_every = 5

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.groups = sprite_group
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill((40, 132, 200))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(300, 400))
        self.vel_x = 0
        self.vel_y = 0
        self.mainclock = 0
        self.current_time = (self.mainclock / 100) / 10
        self.health = PLAYER_HEALTH
        self.movement = {"up": False, "down": False, "left": False, "right": False, "dodge": False}
        self.test_point_topleft = (self.rect.x, self.rect.y)
        self.test_point_topright = (self.rect.x + TILESIZE, self.rect.y)
        self.test_point_bottomleft = (self.rect.x, self.rect.y + TILESIZE)
        self.test_point_bottomright = (self.rect.x + TILESIZE, self.rect.y + TILESIZE)
        
        # Update player initial position
        for row, tiles in enumerate(map_data):
            for col, tile in enumerate(tiles):
                if tile == 'e':
                    self.rect.topleft = (col * TILESIZE, row * TILESIZE)
   
    def reset_movement(self):
        self.vel_x = 0
        self.vel_y = 0
        self.movement = {"up": False, "down": False, "left": False, "right": False, "dodge": False}

    def check_map_change(self, current_map, map_data, prev_map):
        tile_x = self.rect.centerx // TILESIZE
        tile_y = self.rect.centery // TILESIZE

        # Check if player has collided with 'P' to switch to map2
        if current_map == "map.txt" and map_data[tile_y][tile_x] == "P":
            prev_map = current_map
            current_map = g.switch_map("map2.txt", "E")
            
        if current_map == 'map2.txt' and self.rect.x < 10 and map_data[tile_y][tile_x] == "P":
            prev_map = current_map
            current_map = g.switch_map("map.txt", "E")
            
        if current_map == 'map2.txt' and map_data[tile_y][tile_x] == "Q":
            prev_map = current_map
            current_map = g.switch_map("map3.txt", "E")
            
        if current_map == 'map3.txt' and map_data[tile_y][tile_x] == "P":
            prev_map = current_map
            current_map = g.switch_map('map2.txt', "R")

        return current_map
    
    def event_handler(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.movement["up"] = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.movement["down"] = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.movement["left"] = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.movement["right"] = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_z:
                self.movement["dodge"] = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.movement["up"] = False
                self.vel_y = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.movement["down"] = False
                self.vel_y = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.movement["left"] = False
                self.vel_x = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.movement["right"] = False
                self.vel_x = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_z:
                self.movement["dodge"] = False 
            
    def draw_player_stats(self, surf, x, y, pct, color, max_stat, half_stat):
        pct = max(pct, 0)
        BAR_LENGTH = 100
        BAR_HEIGHT = 20
        fill = pct * BAR_LENGTH
        outline_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, BAR_LENGTH, BAR_HEIGHT)
        fill_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, fill, BAR_HEIGHT)
        if pct > max_stat:
            col = GREEN
        elif pct > half_stat:
            col = YELLOW
        else:
            col = RED
        pygame.draw.rect(surf, col, fill_rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(surf, color, outline_rect, 2)
    
    def draw_cirle(self):
        return pygame.draw.circle(win, WHITE, (self.rect.x + TILESIZE // 2, self.rect.y + TILESIZE // 2), TILESIZE, 2)
    
    def radius_check_point(self, test_point):
        if enemy.point_in_circle(*test_point):
            pygame.draw.circle(win, (255, 255, 255), (test_point), 5)
        else:
            pygame.draw.circle(win, (255, 255, 255), (test_point), 5)
    
    def dodge_multiple_dir(self, x_increment, y_increment, clock):        
        print("Hello World")
        while True:
            clock += speed_of_game_movement
            new_clock = round(clock / increment_for_every)
            if clock <= max_time:
                if new_clock * increment_for_every == clock:
                    print("Debug")
                    self.movement["left"] = False
                    self.movement["right"] = False
                    self.movement["up"] = False
                    self.movement["down"] = False
                    self.vel_x += x_increment
                    self.vel_y += y_increment

            else:
                break
            
            print("Loop")
            return self.movement["left"], self.movement["right"], self.movement["up"], self.movement["down"]
        return self.movement["left"], self.movement["right"], self.movement["up"], self.movement["down"]
    def update(self):
        self.test_point_topleft = (self.rect.x, self.rect.y)
        self.test_point_topright = (self.rect.x + TILESIZE, self.rect.y)
        self.test_point_bottomleft = (self.rect.x, self.rect.y + TILESIZE)
        self.test_point_bottomright = (self.rect.x + TILESIZE, self.rect.y + TILESIZE)
        
        if ((self.mainclock / 100) / 10) >= 1:
            self.mainclock += 0
            
        else:
            self.mainclock += 1.6
        self.current_time = (self.mainclock / 100) / 100
        
        self.draw_player_stats(win, 150, 740, (self.mainclock / 100) / 10, BLACK, 1, .5)
        self.draw_player_stats(win, 40, 740, self.health / PLAYER_HEALTH, BLACK, .6, .3)
        self.draw_cirle()

        self.radius_check_point(self.test_point_bottomleft)
        self.radius_check_point(self.test_point_bottomright)
        self.radius_check_point(self.test_point_topleft)
        self.radius_check_point(self.test_point_topright)
        
        self.rect.clamp_ip(0, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight) 

        self.rect.x += self.vel_x
        self.collision_sprites = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, walls, False)
        for sprite in self.collision_sprites:
            if self.vel_x > 0:  # Moving right
                self.rect.right = sprite.rect.left

            elif self.vel_x < 0:  # Moving left
                self.rect.left = sprite.rect.right

        self.rect.y += self.vel_y
        self.collision_sprites = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, walls, False)
        for sprite in self.collision_sprites:
            if self.vel_y > 0:  # Moving down
                self.rect.bottom = sprite.rect.top
            elif self.vel_y < 0:  # Moving up
                self.rect.top = sprite.rect.bottom
        
        # Movement
        if self.movement["up"]:
            self.vel_y = -PLAYER_SPEED
        if self.movement["down"]: 
            self.vel_y = PLAYER_SPEED
        if self.movement["left"]: 
            self.vel_x = -PLAYER_SPEED
        if self.movement["right"]: 
            self.vel_x = PLAYER_SPEED

        if self.movement["dodge"]:
        # Dodge Functionality 
            if self.current_time < .1:
                self.movement["dodge"] = False

            elif self.current_time >= .1:
                self.mainclock = 0

                if self.movement["up"]:
                    self.dodge_multiple_dir(0, -increment, mainclock)
                if self.movement["down"]:
                    self.vel_y = DODGE_DISTANCE
                if self.movement["left"]:
                    self.vel_x = -DODGE_DISTANCE
                if self.movement["right"]:
                    self.vel_x = DODGE_DISTANCE        
                    
class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, map_data):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, walls, sprite_group)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill(BLUE)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect((x * TILESIZE, y * TILESIZE), (TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.x =  x
        self.y = y

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.groups = sprite_group
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill((200, 132, 12))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(ScreenWidth // 2 + 40, ScreenHeight // 2 + 80))
        self.health = MOB_HEALTH
        self.speed = MOB_SPEED
        self.vel_x = 0
        self.vel_y = 0
        self.center = (self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery)  # Center of the enemy
        self.radius = 200
        self.circle_color = (255, 0, 0)  # Red color for the circle

    def point_in_circle(self, x, y):
        return math.sqrt((x - self.center[0]) ** 2 + (y - self.center[1]) ** 2) <= self.radius

    def calculate_distance(self, player):
        dx = player.rect.centerx - self.rect.centerx
        dy = player.rect.centery - self.rect.centery
        distance = math.hypot(dx, dy)
        return distance, dx, dy

    def update(self):
        distance, dx, dy = self.calculate_distance(player)

        self.vel_x = 0
        self.vel_y = 0

        player_center_x, player_center_y = player.rect.centerx, player.rect.centery
        enemy_center_x, enemy_center_y = self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery

        distance_to_player = math.hypot(player_center_x - enemy_center_x, player_center_y - enemy_center_y)

        # Handle collision with walls
        self.rect.clamp_ip(0, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight)

        # Draw the circle only when the player is within a certain distance
        if distance < 1000:  # Adjust the distance threshold as needed
            pygame.draw.circle(win, self.circle_color, (self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery), self.radius, 2)

        # Check if the player is inside the enemy's circle
        if distance_to_player <= self.radius:
            # Move towards the player if the player is inside the circle
            self.vel_x += self.speed * dx / distance
            self.vel_y += self.speed * dy / distance
        
        else:
            # Implement idle movement behavior (move up and down slowly)
            if pygame.time.get_ticks() % 2000 < 1000:  # Change direction every 2 seconds
                self.vel_y = 1  # Move down slowly
                
            else:
                self.vel_y = -1  # Move up slowly

        # Handle collision with the player
        collision = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, sprite_group)
        if collision and isinstance(collision, Player):
            collision.health -= 10
            dx = self.rect.centerx - collision.rect.centerx
            dy = self.rect.centery - collision.rect.centery
            distance = math.hypot(dx, dy)
            if distance != 0:
                # Knock back player in the opposite direction
                pygame.mixer.Sound.play(player_hit)
                collision.rect.x -= 30 * dx / distance
                collision.rect.y -= 30 * dy / distance

        # Horizontal movement
        self.rect.x += self.vel_x
        collision_sprites = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, walls, False)
        for sprite in collision_sprites:
            if self.vel_x > 0:  # Moving right
                self.rect.right = sprite.rect.left
            elif self.vel_x < 0:  # Moving left
                self.rect.left = sprite.rect.right

        # Vertical movement
        self.rect.y += self.vel_y
        collision_sprites = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, walls, False)
        for sprite in collision_sprites:
            if self.vel_y > 0:  # Moving down
                self.rect.bottom = sprite.rect.top
            elif self.vel_y < 0:  # Moving up
                self.rect.top = sprite.rect.bottom
                        
class Button(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen, img, img_alt, x, y, group, command=None, command_args=None, debug=None, collision_offset=(0, 0)):
        super().__init__()
        self.groups = group
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.image = img
        self.image_get = img
        self.image_alt = img_alt
        self.command = command
        self.command_args = command_args
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.screen = screen
        self.debug = debug
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.mx, self.my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # Create collision rect with offset from image rect
        self.collision_offset = collision_offset
        self.collision_rect = pygame.Rect(x + collision_offset[0], y + collision_offset[1], self.rect.width - 2*collision_offset[0], self.rect.height - 2*collision_offset[1])

    def collision(self):
        self.mx, self.my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.collision_rect.collidepoint((self.mx, self.my)):
            self.image = self.image_alt
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                if callable(self.command):
                    self.command(*self.command_args)
        else:
            self.image = self.image_get

    def Debug(self, screen):
        if self.debug:
            screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color("white"), self.collision_rect, 2)
            
    def update(self):
        self.mx, self.my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x, self.y)
        
        # Move collision rect with same offset from image rect
        self.collision_rect.topleft = (self.x + self.collision_offset[0], self.y + self.collision_offset[1])
        self.collision_rect.width = self.rect.width - 2*self.collision_offset[0]
        self.collision_rect.height = self.rect.height - 2*self.collision_offset[1]
        
        self.collision()
        self.Debug(self.screen)

class Slider(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, color, min_volume, max_volume):
        super().__init__()
        self.size = [50, 50]
        self.image = pygame.Surface((self.size[0], self.size[1]))
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))
        self.min_volume = min_volume
        self.max_volume = max_volume
        self.new_volume = 0
        self.step_size = 40  # Increment by 10
        self.snap_positions = [i for i in range(0, ScreenWidth, self.step_size)]
        self.percentage = 0.0
        self.current_snap_index = len(self.snap_positions) // 2  # Start at the middle position
        self.dragging = False

    def update(self):
        global new_volume, default_slider_pos, slider_volume
        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            if self.rect.collidepoint((mx, my)):  # Check if mouse is over the slider
                self.dragging = True
                
            else:
                self.dragging = False

        if self.dragging:
            # Determine the nearest snap position to the current mouse position
            nearest_position_index = min(range(len(self.snap_positions)), key=lambda i: abs(self.snap_positions[i] - mx))
            self.current_snap_index = nearest_position_index

            # Update the slider position based on the nearest snap position
            self.rect.x = self.snap_positions[self.current_snap_index]

            # Calculate volume based on slider position
            self.percentage = self.current_snap_index / (len(self.snap_positions) - 1)
            new_volume = int(self.percentage * (self.max_volume - self.min_volume)) + self.min_volume
            mixer.music.set_volume(new_volume / 100)
            default_slider_pos = new_volume * 10

            if self.rect.x <= 100:
                self.rect.x = 100

            if self.rect.x >= ScreenWidth - 150:
                self.rect.x = ScreenWidth - 150
                
            return new_volume

        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
            self.dragging = False

        if float(self.percentage) >= 1.0:
            decimal_part = 0.99
        else:
            decimal_part = (float(self.percentage) * 100) % 100

        # Print the volume as it changesdefault_slider_pos
        print(f"Current volume: {int(float(self.percentage) * 100)}.{int(decimal_part)}%")
        print(default_slider_pos)
        
        # Set global volume variable
        slider_volume = new_volume

        return new_volume, slider_volume, default_slider_pos

class Line(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, sprites):
        super().__init__()
        self.groups = sprites
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)

    def draw(self, screen, x, y, width, height, col):
        rect = (x, y, width, height)
        pygame.draw.rect = (screen, col, rect)

class Box(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    def draw(self, screen, color, x, y, width, height):
        box_rect = (x, y, width, height)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color(color), box_rect)

class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)  #call Sprite initializer
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(path.join(img_folder, image_file)), (ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight)).convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location

sprite_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
walls = pygame.sprite.Group()
button_sprite = pygame.sprite.Group()
pause_button_sprite = pygame.sprite.Group()
settings_sprite = pygame.sprite.Group()

BackGround = Background('background.png', [0,0])
slider_image = pygame.Surface((200, 20))
slider_image.fill((50, 50, 50))
slider = Slider(default_slider_pos, 50, WHITE, 0, 100)
slider_volume = slider.new_volume

def draw_objects():
    for row, tiles in enumerate(map_data):
        for col, tile in enumerate(tiles):
            if tile == '1':
                Wall(col, row, map_data)
                  
player = Player()
enemy = Enemy()
wall = Wall(0, 0, None)
box = Box()
    
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def switch_map(self, new_map, symbol):
        global current_map, player, walls, enemy, player_mainclock
        player_mainclock = player.mainclock
        current_map = new_map
        load_data(current_map)
        sprite_group.empty()
        player = Player()
        walls.empty()
        enemy = Enemy()

        # Restore player's mainclock time
        player.mainclock = player_mainclock

        # Update player initial position
        for row, tiles in enumerate(map_data):
            for col, tile in enumerate(tiles):
                if tile == symbol:
                    player.rect.topleft = (col * TILESIZE, row * TILESIZE)

        return current_map, draw_objects()

    def reset_game_state(self):
        global playing, current_map, player, walls, enemy, sprite_group
        playing = False
        current_map = 'map.txt'
        sprite_group.empty()
        player = Player()
        walls.empty()
        enemy = Enemy()
        self.main()
    
    def back_to_pause(self):
        global settings
        settings = False
        
        return settings
        
    def main(self):
        Button(win, play_img, play_img_alt, 25, 675, button_sprite, self.play, (), collision_offset=(10, 30))
        Button(win, quit_img, quit_img_alt, 900, 675, button_sprite, exit, (), collision_offset=(10, 30))
        pygame.mixer.music.load(path.join(sound_folder, "main_menu_background.wav"))
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
        while True:
            clock.tick(FPS // 2)
            win.blit(BackGround.image, BackGround.rect)

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                        
            draw_text("GloomBound", pixel_font, WHITE, win, (275, 50))
            
            button_sprite.draw(win)         
            button_sprite.update()
            
            pygame.display.update()
    
    def play(self):
        global playing, slider_volume
        playing = True # Set playing to True before starting game loop
        draw_objects()
        pygame.mixer.music.load(path.join(sound_folder, "play_menu_background.wav"))
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
        while playing:
            clock.tick(FPS)
            win.fill((BGCOLOR))
                
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                player.event_handler(event)
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    self.pause()
                    playing = False
                
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_r:
                    g.switch_map(current_map, "e")
            
            player.check_map_change(current_map, map_data, previous_map)
            sprite_group.draw(win)
            sprite_group.update()
            pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(slider_volume / 100)
            pygame.display.update()
    
    def pause(self):
        global pause
        pause = True
        player.reset_movement()
        
        Button(win, continue_img, continue_img_alt, (ScreenWidth / 2) - (button_size[0]), 200, pause_button_sprite, self.play, (), collision_offset=(0, 70))
        Button(win, settings_img, settings_img_alt, (ScreenWidth / 2) - (button_size[0]), 300, pause_button_sprite, self.settings, (), collision_offset=(0, 70))
        Button(win, main_menu, main_menu_alt, (ScreenWidth / 2) - (button_size[0]), 400, pause_button_sprite, self.reset_game_state, (), collision_offset=(0, 70))
        
        while pause:
            win.fill(BGCOLOR)
            clock.tick(FPS)
            
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
                    
            pause_button_sprite.draw(win)
            pause_button_sprite.update()
            
            pygame.display.update()
        
    def settings(self):
        global settings, new_volume
        settings = True
        Button(win, continue_img, continue_img_alt, (ScreenWidth / 2) - (button_size[0]), 200, settings_sprite, self.back_to_pause, (), collision_offset=(0, 70))
        
        while settings:
            win.fill(BGCOLOR)
            clock.tick(FPS)

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            slider.new_volume = slider.update()

            # Move the Slider
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if slider.rect.collidepoint((mx, my)):
                    slider.rect.centerx = mx
            
            # Draw the Slider
            up_pix_font = pygame.font.Font("Minecraft.ttf", font_size[0])
            draw_text("Master volume", up_pix_font, GREEN, win, (ScreenWidth // 2 - 100, 15))
            box.draw(win, WHITE, 100, 75, 824, 3)

            win.blit(slider.image, slider.rect)
            settings_sprite.draw(win)
            settings_sprite.update()
            pygame.display.update()
    
    def run(self):
        self.main()

g = Game()
g.run()
```

Comment: If you're talking about `while run`, then you should check the value of `run` before entering the loop. There's *absolutely* no way we can tell. See why everyone says that globals are a bad thing?

Comment: The loop never changes the value of `run`. So it seems wrong to use that as the `while` condition. Use `while True:` if you want to loop until the `break` is executed.

Comment: This code does not match the git repo. which one do you want us to debug?

Answer (score -1):

Setting the repo aside as the code there does not match the code here. The code from this post is:

```py
    def dodge_multiple_dir(self, x_increment, y_increment, clock):        
        print("Hello World")
        while True:
            clock += speed_of_game_movement
            new_clock = round(clock / increment_for_every)
            if clock <= max_time:
                if new_clock * increment_for_every == clock:
                    print("Debug")
                    self.movement["left"] = False
                    self.movement["right"] = False
                    self.movement["up"] = False
                    self.movement["down"] = False
                    self.vel_x += x_increment
                    self.vel_y += y_increment
            else:
                break
            
            print("Loop")
            return self.movement["left"], self.movement["right"], self.movement["up"], self.movement["down"]
        return self.movement["left"], self.movement["right"], self.movement["up"], self.movement["down"]
```

With additional context that inside the method we will start with:

```py
code = 0                   # as passed
speed_of_game_movement = 3 # global
increment_for_every = 5    # global
max_time = 80              # global
```

When `dodge_multiple_dir()` is called, it is passed a `clock` of `0`.

So, what happens...

You `print("Hello World")` then enter the loop.

Inside the loop, `clock` becomes `3` then `new_clock` (`0.6`) rounds to `1`.

You then enter the first `if` condition as `clock` is less then `max_time` but do not enter the second as `5 <> 3`

You then fall out of the nested `if` statements and finally

```
print("Loop")
return self.movement["left"], self.movement["right"], self.movement["up"], self.movement["down"]
```

Maybe move that `return` into the innermost `if` after incrementing velocities?